# Find the roots of the polynomial $x^5-5x^4-35x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, given that the roots form an arithmetic progression.

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic-progressions

> Find the roots of the polynomial $x^5-5x^4-35x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, given that the roots form an arithmetic progression.

**What I've tried :**

Letting $\alpha$, $\alpha+d$, $\alpha+2d$, $\alpha+3d$, $\alpha+4d$ be the roots of $p(x)$ .

I got sum of roots = $5\alpha + 10d = 5$ or $\alpha + 2d = 1$

So, $1$ is one of the roots of $p(x)$ .

Equating $p(x) = 0$ , I got $a+b+c = 39$ .

And from product of roots ,
I got $(1 - 4d^2)(1 - d^2) = c$ .

I don't know how to further deduce the remaining roots of $p(x)$ .

Comment: @AnneBauval because $a+2d$ is a root

Comment: To the OP: You learned far more in your first step than just 1 is a root.  You have tried exactly one reasonable idea afterwards; what other information could you use?

Comment: a,b,c give no information. Concentrate on -35. And your roots are now $1-2d,1-d,1,1+d,1+2d.$

Comment: Yeah @AnneBauval i considered roots now as $1-2d,1-d,1,1+d,1+2d$ but what's next ?

Comment: @AnneBauval but these are "10" terms not 3 or 4 or 5 

Comment: Well @JBL I'd one more idea after getting $(x - 1)$ as a factor of $p(x)$ and dividing $p(x)$ by it , I got a quartic polynomial $x^4 - 4x^3 - 39x^2 + (a - 39)x - c$ . Can it be helpful idea ?

Comment: 1) Use *all* 5 Viete's (or Vieta's) formulas. 2) Can we assume that all roots are real ? It is not said... 3) (a detail) Calculations are simpler if you assume that roots are $\alpha-2d, \alpha-d, \alpha, \alpha+d, \alpha+2d$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler calculation, knowing the algebraic identity of  $(\sum a)^2 - 2 \sum ab = \sum a^2$.

By Vieta's formula, you know that the sum of roots is 5, so the middle term is 1. Let the difference be $d$.
Using the algebraic identity,
$$  5^2 + 2 \times 35 = (1 - 2d)^2 + ( 1- d)^2 + 1^2 + (1+d)^2 + (1+2d)^2  = 5 + 10d^2.$$

Hence, $ d = \pm 3$, and the roots are $ -5, -2, 1, 4, 7$.

Comment: (+1) Typo in the last expression: $(1 - 2d)^2 + ( 1- d)^2 + 1^2 + (1+d)^{\color{blue}{2}} + (1+2d)^{\color{blue}{2}}$

Comment: As cooler as i thought it would be if it's @Calvin Lin to answer

Answer (score 4):

You found that your roots are $1,1\pm d,1\pm2d.$

- Now (ignoring $a,b,c$), $p(x)=(x-1)(x^4-4x^3-39x^2+\dots),$ so
  $$\begin{align}-39&=\Bigl((1-2d)+(1+2d)\Bigr)\Bigl((1-d)+(1+d)\Bigr)+(1-2d)(1+2d)+(1-d)(1+d)\\&=4+(1-4d^2)+(1-d^2)\\&=6-5d^2\end{align}$$
  hence $d=\pm3,$ so your five roots are
  $$-5,-2,1,4,7.$$
- Alternatively, if you don't want to factor out $x-1$, you can calculate directly the 2nd elementary symmetric polynomial of the *five* roots:
  $$\begin{align}-35&=\Bigl((1-2d)+(1+2d)\Bigr)\Bigl((1-d)+(1+d)\Bigr)+(1-2d)(1+2d)+(1-d)(1+d)+1\Bigl((1-2d)+(1+2d)+(1-d)+(1+d)\Bigr)\\&=4+(1-4d^2)+(1-d^2)+4\\&=10-5d^2\end{align}$$
  and the same conclusion follows.
- A third way is to do the change of variable $x=1+y:$
  $$\begin{align}p(x)&=(1+y)^5-5(1+y^4)-35(1+y)^3+\dots\\&=(y^5+5y^4+10y^3)-5(y^4+4y^3)-35y^3+\dots\\&=y^5-45y^3+\dots\end{align}$$
  hence
  $$\begin{align}-45&=(2d-2d)(d-d)+(2d)(-2d)+d(-d)=-5d^2.
  \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks mam but i already understood from @Another User's answer 

Comment: I know but my calculations are less tedious. (Since you showed in comments you were afraid of calculating a sum of 10 products.)

Comment: Anyway yeah i actually tried that 4 degree polynomial to get rid of those 10 terms for only 6 terms but accidentally, i mistaken $6 - 5d^2 = 39$ instead of $-39$ anyway thanks for clarifying my mistake 

Comment: Note also that you did not need to bother about $a,b,c$ nor make the full division.

Comment: Well what did u mean by that , I did the whole division 'cause it was not easier to factorise or maybe I've not thought for factorising 

Comment: Learn to not laugh at helpful users, but show gratitude that you received answers from cracks. This attitude will guide the way towards learning more, and better. F.e. ask yourself why it is that you falsly went down road a, when road b is preferable.

Comment: @Ash_Blanc I am not sure to understand your last comment. What I mean by that is that you can stop your division as soon as you get the coefficient $-39.$ You do not need to finish it.

Answer (score 3):

You know that $\alpha+2d=1$. And you also know that
\begin{multline}
\alpha  (d+\alpha )+(2 d+\alpha ) (d+\alpha )+(3
   d+\alpha ) (d+\alpha )+(4 d+\alpha ) (d+\alpha
   )+\\+\alpha  (2 d+\alpha )+\alpha  (3 d+\alpha )+(2
   d+\alpha ) (3 d+\alpha )+\alpha  (4 d+\alpha )+\\+(2
   d+\alpha ) (4 d+\alpha )+(3 d+\alpha ) (4 d+\alpha
   )=35,
\end{multline}
which means that $35 d^2+40 \alpha  d+10 \alpha ^2=35$. And this, together the fact that $\alpha+2d=1$ will give you that the set of roots is $\{-5,-2,1,4,7\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the third method that **Anne Bauval** suggested:

Having determined that one zero of $ \ x^5 - 5x^4 - 35x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c \ $ must be $ \ 1 \ $ if the five real zeroes are to be in arithmetic progression, we can perform synthetic or polynomial division to find the factorization $ \ (x - 1)·p(x) \ = \ (x - 1)·( \ x^4 - 4x^3 - 39x^2 + [a - 39]·x + [a + b - 39] \ ) \ \   $  (as you wrote in one of your comments).

If we "shift to the left" by $ \ 1 \ $ this reduced polynomial $ \ p(x) \ \ , \ $ its zeroes will be $ \ -2d \ , \ -d  \ , \ +d \ , \ + 2d \ \ , \ $ so it is now an even function. This new polynomial is
$$ q(x) \ \ = \ \ p(x + 1) \ \ =  \ \ x^4 \ - \ 45x^2 \ + \ (a - 125)x \ + \ (2a + b - 120) \ \ .  $$
This tells us immediately that $ \ a \ = \ 125 \ \ $ and that this even-symmetry polynomial is $  \ q(x) $ $   = \ x^4   -   45x^2   +    (130 + b ) \ \ . \ $  We require that $ \ \pm d \ \ , \ \ \pm 2d \ \ $ be zeroes of $ \ q(x) \ \ . \ $ We *could* solve for the prospective zeroes of this biquadratic polynomial and find the value of $ \ b \ $ that produces the proper spacing between those zeroes. But it is rather easier to observe that
$$ d^4 \ - \ 45d^2 \ + \ (130 + b) \ \ = \ \ (2d)^4 \ - \ 45·(2d)^2 \ + \ (130 + b) $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ 15d^4 \ - \ 135d^2 \ \ = \ \ 15d^2·(d^2 - 9) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .  $$
As $ \ d \ = \ 0 \ $ is   "spurious" since all of the zeroes would be identically zero, the "useful" solution is $ \ d \ = \ \pm 3 \ \ . \ $  The zeroes of $ \ q(x) \ $ are then $ \ -6 \ \ , \ \ -3 \ \ , \ \ +3 \ \ , \ \ +6 \ \ , \ $ giving us the zeroes of the original quintic polynomial as $ \ \boxed{-5 \ \ , \ \ -2 \ \ , \ \ 1 \ \ , \ \ 4 \ \ , \ \ 7} \ \ . \ $

Note that we have never needed to know the unknown coefficients of the quintic other than $ \ a \ \ , \ \ $ although we can now readily determine that polynomial to be $ \ x^5 - 5x^4 - 35x^3 + 125x^2 + 194x - 280 \ \ . $